# Metadata to sharepoint forders in an library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, metadata, sharepoint-permissions

Can someone tell me is it possible to define metadata to folder level documents?

like different metadata to different folders.

[image: the folders in my document library]

[image: Documents inside the folder]

Comment: You cannot assign metadata/custom columns to folders.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Then if I add all the documents to one single library and create metadata to differentiate the files, is it possible to give permissions depending on the metadata?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using Flow/Power Automate or even with a webhook but I suggest to do not use these approaches to have correct permissions. I suggest to operate at the document library level without flows and creating more than one library if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's by design that we cannot add metadata(custom columns) to folders.

As a workaround, you could use document set to achieve this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234

First, you need to enable Document Sets for a site collection:  go to site settings-> Site collection features, activate the feature Documet Sets.

[image]

Then, you need to add the Document Set content type to the document library: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60

After a Document Set content type has been added to a document library, you can use it to create new multi-document work products. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-manage-document-sets-c71d5796-d559-48de-b1b3-42383bdd13ea